# Powershell Select-Object how to get array of values

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to delete contents of few folders. 
What I have:

```
$Config = @{
    InstallPath = 'C:\Program Files\App'
    SubPaths = @('www\app1', 'www\app2', 'www\app3')
}
```

And here is the code to get contents:

```
$Config.SubPaths | Select-Object { Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ } | Get-ChildItem
```

But it doesn't work, because `Get-ChildItem` receives object like below:

```
@{ Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ =C:\Program Files\App\www\app1}
```

Error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{ Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ =C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:85
+ ... elect-Object { Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ } | Get-ChildItem
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{ Join-Path $C...stallPath $_ =D:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoun
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How can I convert result of `Select-Object` to simple array of strings? Or any other approach to make code better?

Comment: `$Config.SubPaths | ForEach-Object { Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ } | Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you are getting are because you made a new object with the the literal property `Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_`. Instead...

```
$Config.SubPaths | ForEach-Object { Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_ } | Get-ChildItem
```

You are not trying to select a property of a single subpath but generate a string from each of the SubPaths. Using `Foreach-object` instead to iterate over the collection should get you the results you are looking for.

While you could create custom objects and properties using calculated properties I figure this is not the direction you are going for. But to answer the question in the title you could have done this:

```
$Config.SubPaths | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={Join-Path $Config.InstallPath $_}} | 
    Get-ChildItem
```

`Get-ChildItem` should bind to the path property of the new object were are making

Comment: Thanks, that's exacly what I looking for.